# help solving a probability exercise

Tags: probability, problem-solving, trees, bayes-theorem

I'm new here and I would like to know if anyone can help me or give me an insight. I just have this exercise below to solve and I'm having a hard time doing it. Im studying the tree diagram method and the Bayes' theroem so maybe I'll need to use one of them...

**A digital computer uses words of 32 binary digits, these being 0 or 1.
Knowing that the probability of misreading a binary digit is 10^-3,
find the probability that two digits are misread in a word.**

thanks in advance

Comment: Binomial distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint: Binomial distribution**

$$P(X=x)={n\choose x}p^x q^{n-x}$$

Where
$$n=\text{Number of trials}\\
x=\text{Number of succeses}\\
p=\text{Probability of succeding in one trial}\\
q=1-p$$